# How to correct HP recovery full through "other files"?

Tags: windows-7

I'm a bit confused, as I didn't find anything on the net about this problem.
On a HP computer I looked at the D drive is the HP_Recovery. The drive itself has 18,48 GB space with the databackup taking up 2,81 GB.

Still though windows is always crying out that the disk is full as "other files" are taking up 15,66GB.

After googling and also trying to find anything in the configurations I neither managed to find out WHAT in the computers name those other files could be (in the windows explorer only the "main directory of the recovery" shows up) nor how to eliminate those files.

So the question would be: Is there any way to eliminate those (unseen) "other files"? Or in the very least find out what these files are?

Answer (score 0):

So with the HP_Recovery partition I'm surprised you're actually able to see it. I assume it shows up in File Explorer/Explorer(*Windows 8.1 or 10/ Windows 7 and below respectfully*) since it has been assigned a drive letter. That partition in my experience usually has it's type set as *Recovery* and shouldn't be seen.  If the drive is showing free space but Windows claims it's full then the partition type is likely set to *Recovery* and this is why you can't use its free space as it's a protected partition. Although not recommended you should be able to change it's partition type using [DiskPart SETID](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753840(v=ws.11).aspx#Parameters) if you so choose.

First you'll want to determine the partition type to see if this is even necessary. You can do this easily by pressing *WinKey + R to open the **Run Dialog Box** > type `diskmgmt.msc` (press enter) > Click **Yes** on the **UAC elevation prompt***. Look for the **HP_Recovery** volume in the top list and look for its *partition type* and *status*. If it is a protected partition it should say something other than **Type: Basic** and **Status: Healthy(Primary Partition)** [Disk Management Example Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR7x4.png).

If that's the case and you want to change partition type make note of the disk it's linked to.  You'll notice at the bottom the volumes are listed next to their disk.  For me **Volume D** resides on **Disk 2**. For you **D:** likely resides on **Disk 0**. Now you'll want to open **Diskpart**. You can do this the same way we opened **diskmgmt**.  *WinKey + R > Type `Diskpart` (press enter) > Click **"Yes"** to **UAC Elevation** > type* `sel disk X` again where **X** is the disk number **Volume D** resides on.

Next type `list disk` and look all the way to the right where it says **GPT** if there's an * next to disk X than you'll want to use the **GPT** command instead of the **MBR command** for setting the partition type. Next type `list part` and look down the list for the partition that matches the size of **Volume D**, ignore the offset.

Once found type `sel part X` again where **X** matches the partition number that is the same size as **(D:)HP_Recovery**.  Okay, finally, if your disk had the **GPT** * you'll want to use this command `set id=ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7`, else if it did not have the * you'll want to use this command `set id=07 override`.  Afterwards type `exit` and close out **diskpart** and then **reboot your system**.  The changes might take effect immediately but just to be safe it's better to reboot.  The drive should now be accessible and your restore file should be left intact.

---

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you need to keep the HP Recovery partition at all? I would suggest simply deleting it and extending your main partition. Better yet, I'd suggest a complete clean install of Windows on a cleaned disk (with Windows 10 this is very easy, as the installer will accept any 7+ key, including the UEFI burnt-in ones), so you start without any HP junkware slowing down your computer and taking space.